# How can I use audio files from server folder in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, audio, import, src

I have 2 projects: react app and server folder. There is a upload folder in the server folder where audios are stored.
How can I use the audio from this folder in react app?
If I write src = '../../../../server_training/uploads/file_name.ogg' it's don't work.

This is my project structure: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk68W.png)

I'm try

```
 <AudioPlayer
    //src='./../../training_server/uploads/file_name.ogg'
    //src = "trainer\training_server\uploads\file_name.ogg"
    //src='../training_server/uploads/file_name.ogg'

    showJumpControls={false}
    layout={'horizontal-reverse'}
    autoPlay={false}
/>
```

Аnd when I try to import this folder, an error occurs

```
 import * as files from '../../../../training_server/uploads'
```

Cannot find module '../../../../training_server/uploads' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: You have to expose the files using your server so they are accessible using an endpoint and then you can directly use urls or fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 import * as files from '../../../../training_server/uploads'
```

This statement will import the audio files and keep them inside of the .js assets. This is not a great idea since audio files are much larger than images. It also doesn't work since a loader hasn't been written.

A better way to do it is like this

```html
    <audio
        controls
        src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3">
            <a href="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3">
                Download audio
            </a>
    </audio>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

You can replace the src="" with the write url structure where your audio files are.